# Auto fill data in form connected to Excel file

Tags: office365, powerapps

I'm designing PowerApps form which is connected to Excel table stored on Onedrive.
All of columns are displayed in my form, however one of them I need to auto fill with data based on user login. So, I have changed it to "available items" type (not sure if I'm translating it to english right) and write formula: **items = User()**

The problem is that it gives me an email address instead of user name.
If I'm changing it to **User().FullName** it gives me a formula error message.

Labels works fine, all user functions works correct. The problem exist only in table connected to Excel file.

Can you help me?